# Multi year values in 1 row to multiple rows

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

[image]

Hi, I need some suggestion on scenario when multi year  values are present in same row in the source data feed as shown in Lease_Annual_Rent table below, and in the data warehouse side, 'Lease Annual Rent Fact' table which has values for each year in a separate rows.

Is there any advantage/downside of following this approach in dimensional modeling. One issue I see that number of rows will be 11 times more than data feed.

Comment: "One issue I see that number of rows will be 11 times more than data feed"  - why is that an issue?

Comment: Hi, yes, its not an issue. please tell me if you think this approach is correct. I don't have extensive experience in dimensional modeling.